# Setuptools package discovery

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have below package tree for my project

```
└── src
|    ├── mypkg1
|    │   ├── module1.py
|    │   ├── module2.py
|    │   └── __init__.py
|    |   |-- setup.py
|    |   |__ requirements.py 
|    └── mypkg2
|        ├── module1.py
|        └── __init__.p
|
|---- base
|      |----- init.py
|      |----- module1.py
```

Note - src and base are at same level.

How should I configure `setup.py` file, so that I can install `base` and `mypkg1` packages only and exclude `mypkg2`.

I have tried mentioning `['base','mypkg1']` in packages but didn't worked also tried using `find_packages()` it will show up only `mypkg1` and `mypkg2`.

Comment: Show (the relevant parts of) the `setup.py` and/or `setup.cfg` file(s) as well as their position in the project tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple things to take care of due to the complex codebase layout. Also, I'm not sure why you are showing the setup script inside `src/mypkg1` - invoking it from there will not find anything outside of `src` and thus you'll have no chance to include `base`. In the below example, I switched to the root directory containing both `src` and `base` dirs:

```
project_root
├── src/
├── base/
└── setup.py
```

#### Package discovery

Since `base` is under the project root, it will be discovered by plain `find_packages` invocation:

```
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> find_packages()
['base']
```

To find packages under `src`, pass it via `where` argument:

```
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> find_packages(where='src')
['mypkg1', 'mypkg2']
```

To exclude `mypkg2`, pass it via the list in `exclude` argument:

```
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> find_packages(where='src', exclude=['mypkg2'])
['mypkg1']
```

#### Package structure mapping and file inclusion

Calling `setuptools.setup()` as is with the collected packages will only work for `base`, since `mypkg1` is not on the root level. You have to map its location via `package_dir`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)
```

This, however, instructs `setup()` to look for files of *all* packages in `src`, which makes files under `base` not findable. You thus have to map it explicitly:

```
setup(
    ...,
    package_dir={'': 'src', 'base': 'base'},
)
```

#### Complete minimal setup script

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='...',
    version='...',
    packages=find_packages() + find_packages(where='src', exclude=['mypkg2']),
    package_dir={'': 'src', 'base': 'base'},
)
```

Now when e.g. building a wheel, this will produce the following file layout:

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  06-24-2022 21:55   base/__init__.py
        0  06-24-2022 21:55   base/module1.py
        0  06-24-2022 21:54   mypkg1/__init__.py
        0  06-24-2022 21:54   mypkg1/module1.py
        0  06-24-2022 21:54   mypkg1/module2.py
```

Comment: thanks a lot !! , one more issue I am facing is we have to hardcode exclude part but can I make it dynamic by passing some arguments to setup.py to tell which one to exclude using `pip` command. As sometime I have to exclude mypkg1 and install mypckg2, is that possible?

Comment: You can pass the packages to exclude via e.g. an environment variable. Beware though, that it will only be applied when installing from a source dist (`.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2`, `.zip`). Once you have built a wheel, there's no `setup.py` and the packages that landed in the wheel can't be included or excluded anymore.

Comment: nope environment variable is not an feasible option for my project, I have seen overriding install command  option. I have coded something but not able to reach to perfect solution.

Comment: same question is posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770063/setuptools-creating-custom-command-to-install-selected-package-dynamically