# Setuptools: Creating custom command to install selected package dynamically

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I have following package tree , I want to install the particular package from `src` and `base` (always install with selected package from src). I am trying to create custom command so that using pip I can pass list of packages names to install as follow:
`pip install setup.py --install-option="--package=package_1, package_2"` , so this should install package_1, package_2 along with base package using single setup.py(let me know if I need more at particular package level too)
I am following below folder tree.

```
parent_package
└── src
|    ├── mypkg1
|    │   ├── module1.py
|    │   ├── module2.py
|    │   └── __init__.py 
|    └── mypkg2
|        ├── module1.py
|        └── __init__.py
|
|---- base
|      |----- init.py
|      |----- module1.py 
|---- setup.py
|---- requirements.txt
```

I have written code as below which is giving an error

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install

import sys
# new install class
class InstallCommand(install):
    # pass argument subpackage from pip install to setup.py
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ('subpackage=', None, None),  
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        sys.stdout.write(f"Inside initialize_options--->")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        install.initialize_options(self)
        self.subpackage = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        sys.stdout.write(f"Inside finalize_options--->")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        install.finalize_options(self)

    def run(self):

        if self.subpackage is None:
            sys.stdout.write(f"Inside IF condition--->")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            # install all sub-packages
            subpackages = find_packages() + ['src.'+x for x in find_packages(where='src')]#['src.'+x for x in find_packages('./src', exclude=['*.tests', '*.tests.*', 'tests.*', 'tests'])]
            sys.stdout.write(f"packages to install --->{subpackages}")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            self.distribution.packages += ['src'] + subpackages 

        else:  
            subpackages = self.subpackage.split(', ')
            # print("Install sub-packages:", self.subpackage)
            # install only specific sub-packages
            subpackages = ['src.'+x for x in subpackages]
            self.distribution.packages += find_packages() + subpackages#['src'] + subpackages
        sys.stdout.write(f"packages distribution install --->{self.distribution.packages}")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        install.run(self)

metadata = dict(
    name='my_connector',
    packages=[],
    install_requires=[],
    setup_requires=[],
    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallCommand
    }
    )

setup(**metadata)
```

Issue :-

After debugging I could see it's always going in my else condition and installing all the available packages. I tried to print flow , I could see it's first going in  `initialize_options` function and making `self.subpackage = None` causing entering into else part and not in if.

How should I check for subpackage which I have mentioned in command running as follow:

```
pip install . -v --install-option="--subpackage=package_1,"
```

Comment: What command are you invoking for installation?

Comment: Also, `self.subpackage` should probably be `self.package`.

Comment: Yes, I have already did that change , but still same issue.

Comment: I have updated error part, can you please have a look.

Comment: @hoefling, I have corrected now all working fine but the command I am using with that it's not able to find subpackage  which I have mentioned.

Comment: @hoefling, updated my issue part now.

Comment: Most likely it's a cache issue. Try smth like `rm -rf build/ my_connector.egg-info/ && pip install . --no-cache-dir --install-option="--subpackage=mystuff"`.

Comment: nope , still always going and setting self.subpackage = None

Comment: I have now put the code locally and I can't reproduce the issue if cleaning up the cached stuff before reinstalling. Sure, `self.subpackage` is set to `None` in `initialize_options` - but then `finalize_options` is called, where the actual parsing of the command line args is done, and the attribute is fed with the correct value. Add smth like `print('self.subpackage read:', repr(self.subpackage))` after `install.finalize_options(self)` to verify that.

Comment: If I do `rm -rf build dist my_connector.egg-info && pip install . --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall -vvv --disable-pip-version-check --install-option="--subpackage=mypkg1" && pip show -f my-connector`, I see `base` and `mypkg1` installed. If I change the last option to `subpackage=mypkg1, mypkg2`, I see `mypkg2` installed in addition. Although it's weird to have spaces in command line args - you might get problems with escaping that on Windows, can't say for sure.

Comment: Awesome it works, please add it as an answer.

Comment: Also is there a chance that I can install package(passed as an parameters)at base level instead of in src folder.

Comment: Do you mean having `mypkg1` instead of `src.mypkg1` installed? This is because you didn't configure `package_dir`, as was discussed in your previous question. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: any I got the answer for it, Thanks a lot for your effort.